# Laying Flooring Under Water Heater?

Tags: flooring, water-heater, installation

Looking to add some laminate under the laundry area of our garage, including a water heater (which is not directly on the floor, but instead on a metal table per previous owners). We're DIYing it and on a **very** tight budget, so I'm trying to avoid calling a plumber to reinstall the water heater.

Flooring is only 10mm thick, pad is attached. In theory, how safe would it be to use a car jack to raise the water heater *just* enough to install under the table the water heater is on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd be concerned that the pipes the heater is connected to don't have sufficient wiggle room. Can you shorten the table by 1cm and leave the water heater where it is?

Comment: It takes five seconds to turn the heater off.  It takes another five seconds to turn the water valves off.  10 seconds to greatly increase safety.

Comment: Pictures would help.  It really depends on how your water heater is currently connected.  If it's all with flexible connectors or electric cable, it should be feasible.  If there are solid connections, then it would be harder to DIY if you're not plumbing-savvy.

Answer (score 2):

if you can jack the heater safely and only just to slide flooring under, I say it's ok. be sure there is a bit of room for the pipes to move that 10mm.

I would not use laminate flooring anywhere where it could get water on it, as the water will ruin it.  That is where LVP or solid core vinyl products are superior.  An added bonus is that good quality LVP is usually about 6.5mm...so even less jacking needed.

Comment: The water proof flooring is a better choice than the water resistant flooring.